# How to find position of a character in a string in PHP

Tags: php, strpos

How to find positions of a character in a string or sentence in php

```
$char   = 'i';
$string = 'elvis williams';
$result = '3rd ,7th and 10th'.
```

I tried strpos..but no use..

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You can format source code with the `{}` toolbar button. (ajreal has done it for you this time.)

Answer (score 17):

This will give you the position of $char in $string:

```
$pos = strpos($string, $char);
```

If you want the position of all occurences of $char in string:

```
$positions = array();
$pos = -1;
while (($pos = strpos($string, $char, $pos+1)) !== false) {
    $positions[] = $pos;
}

$result = implode(', ', $positions);

print_r($result);
```

Test it here: http://codepad.viper-7.com/yssEK3

Comment: wow that saves my time..is there any possibility to rewrite the logic in recursive method??